# GridBagLayout component ignoring width?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

sorry if this has been asked before but I have spent ages searching with no success.

I have a panel in which I'm trying to add some components using GridBagLayout.

The Problem is that for some reason I can't figure out - the JTextArea I am trying to add seems to ignore the width being assigned to it - it seems to accept the height no problem.

All components are added fine except for the text area - which should have a width of 3, but displays with a width of 1.

I cannot understand why this is, can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Code: (EDIT)

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Content master = new Content();
    master.createAndShowGui();
}

}
package test;

//import declarations

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Content

{   
//declare class variables

private JDialog schoolFrame = new JDialog();
private JPanel schoolPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
private JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
private JButton exit = new JButton("Quit");
private JButton portView = new JButton("View Portfolio");
private JButton payView = new JButton("View Payment Info");
private GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
private JLabel payAmount = new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
private JButton subPayment = new JButton("Submit Payment");
private JLabel subLabels[] = new JLabel[5];
private JTextField subFields[] = new JTextField[5];
private JButton subGradeChange = new JButton("Submit Changes");
JLabel tester = new JLabel();
JLabel tester2 = new JLabel("jjjjjjj");


public Content(){

}

private void setOptions(JComponent b,int weightx,int weighty,int x,int y,int width,int height)
{
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;    
    c.weightx = weightx;
    c.weighty = weighty;
    c.gridy = y;
    c.gridx = x;
    c.gridwidth = width;
    c.gridheight = height;
    schoolPanel.add(b, c);
}

//method to create and display the GUI

public JDialog createAndShowGui()
{   
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    schoolFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    schoolFrame.setContentPane(schoolPanel);
    schoolFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,600)); 
    schoolFrame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    text.setEditable(false);
    schoolFrame.setModal(true);
    schoolFrame.setTitle("Simple School System: House Head");
    setOptions(tester, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1);
    setOptions(portView,1,1,0,0,2,1);
    setOptions(text,1,1,2,0,3,7);
    for(int i=0;i<subLabels.length;i++){
        subLabels[i] = new JLabel();
        subFields[i] = new JTextField();
        subLabels[i].setText("Subject: ");
        subFields[i].setText("Enter Grade");
        setOptions(subLabels[i],1,1,0,i+1,1,1);
        setOptions(subFields[i],1,1,1,i+1,1,1);
    }
    setOptions(subGradeChange,1,1,1,6,1,1);
    setOptions(exit,1,1,0,6,1,1);
    exit.addActionListener
  (
    new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
            int quit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Exit","Are you sure",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(quit==0)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                schoolFrame.dispose();
                hideUpdate();
            }
    }
  });

    //pack components before displaying frame

    schoolFrame.pack();
    text.setPreferredSize(text.getPreferredSize());
    schoolFrame.pack();
    schoolFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    schoolFrame.setVisible(true);
    return schoolFrame;
}



//method to update the contents of the frame

private void hideUpdate()
{
    schoolFrame.setVisible(false);      
    schoolFrame.pack();
    schoolFrame.repaint();
    schoolFrame.pack();
    schoolFrame.setVisible(true);       
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Sorry about that - I have updated the code.

Comment: unsure exactly how you want it to look. The buttons are supposed to be above and below the textarea? At the moment the textarea is just to the left.

Comment: Oliver, Is this what you get from running the code? When I run it - the exact code above, I get 3 columns, with a button top left spanning 2 cols, then labels/textfields/buttons below this large button in two columns. Effectively two columns where the top button takes up both. The text area should take up the entirety of column 3 - which should have a width greater than that of the first two columns, but displays with a width of about 1 column. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: To be clear - literally all I'm looking for here is how to ensure the JTextArea takes up more proportional space of the panel - buttons ~30% width, text ~70% width. NOTHING seems to fix this, any variation of set(preferred)Size() that I have tried does nothing, at all. All I want is the panel to have 5 columns - with the text area taking up 3,4 and 5, yet this seems to be impossible at the minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate 3 columns width there should be something in column 2 and 3.

So in fact you add all your components in one column. LayoutManager can't figure out width of column 2 and 3 because there is no components in the columns. So their widths are 0 and `your textarea's width =1st column widht + 0 + 0`

Comment: Thanks for replying - portView component is positioned in 0,0, but spans 2 columns, therefore taking up column 2? And then the buttons created in loop take up 0,y and 1,y respectively, so all these components should take up the first two columns? Then textarea is added to the 3rd column. Sorry if I'm not understanding what you have said.

Comment: try to add e.g. a JLabel to column 2 and to column 3 (width=1) and see the result

Comment: This doesn't seem to help I'm afraid - adding a label to col 2 doesn't seem to affect anything, but when I add a label to col 3 (adding random text) it just increases the size of the column marginally (I'm assuming based on the length of the string in the label).